# prevent specific input from being sent on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have an radio group selecting the user what to search for. The inputs the user isn't searching for are hidden with JavaScript. How do I prevent them from being submitted? E.g. if radio1 is selected, I don't want to have the input with the name `"search-by-date"` to be submitted. Is there any way I can do it except removing the name attribute? If removing the name attribute is the only/best way, where is the right place to do it?

Thanks

Comment: You must do it server-side anyway. You can "submit forms" without even using a browser and the server wouldn't know the difference

Comment: Set it to disabled e.g. `control.disabled = true`. But this should be done server-side, doing it client side makes no sense.

Comment: @Esailija right, I have to do it anyway server-side but because I want  to say "look, user, this generated query string is how you use my API" and therefore it would be great to discard the unused fields before submit

Comment: @levu in that case you can just set `.disabled = true` (or jQuery `.prop("disabled", true)` like RobG said. Disabled inputs are not submitted by the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable the field.

```
$('#your_form_id').submit(function(){
    if($("input:radio[name=radio1]").prop('checked')){
        $("input:radio[name=search-by-date]").prop('disabled',true);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A script i once made for not sending empty values, it might help, it also disables the form if nothing is filled in:

```
$("form").submit(function() {
  var count = $(this).find(':input').filter(function() {
    return $(this).val() != "";
  }).length;
  if (count > 0) {
    $(this).find(':input[value=""]').attr("disabled", "disabled");
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: i see in the comments of your question the new prop() function that is enabled sinds jquery 1.6 so you can replace .attr("disabled", "disabled") with .prop("disabled"), it has the same result btw

Answer (score 1):

Took Gijs code example and made it a bit smaller:

```
$("form").submit(function() {
    var inputs = $(this).find(':input'),
        emptyInputs = inputs.filter('[value=""]');
    return inputs.length > emptyInputs.length && emptyInputs.prop("disabled", true).length > 0;
});
```

it checks if all inputs are empty then return false but if there are inputs that has values and there are inputs that are empty, return true and set empty inputs to disabled